# Unable to send topic based notification using firebase admin

Tags: node.js, oauth, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have one api in the node backend which will send push notification. I am using firebase-admin npm package and using subscribeToTopic method to send notification. Getting this error on server.

> FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect ECONNREFUSED 142.250.192.77:443. Error code: ECONNREFUSED

I had whitelisted urls which is in the firebase sdk json file.

Not getting idea what causing this issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).